# How to add a library to eclipse C project?

Tags: c, linux, eclipse

I need to add a C library to C project in Eclipse indigo.
What I've done so far.
I've downloaded and installed the library.
All headers are in folder /usr/include, library.so files are in folder /usr/lib.
After having read a tutorial I tried to do it like this:
When in Eclipse -> Project -> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> GCC C Linker -> Libaries -> Add libary -> "ibxml2" ( library name is libxml2 )
But it still doesn't work.
I am a super newbie at Linux, so please could you give me some advise how to do that?
[image: there is a screenshot, that might be helpfful]

By the way one more thing. After creating a new C/C++ Project when I run an error occurs " Launch failed! Binary not found". I checked "Binary Parsers" in Project's Settings and "Elf Parser" is set ( I've read that it is OK for Linux ), so what is wrong? It is not so important, since it works when I first only build project and then run it, but maybe there is a way to solve that too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In linker options, you should not add "libxml2", but just "xml2". All binary libraries in Linux (so files) have a "lib" prefix that is not a part of library name.

Comment: It still doesn't work I get such an error:
/usr/local/include/libxml2/libxml/xmlmemory.h:16:31: fatal error: libxml/xmlversion.h: There is no such file or folder. ( I checked the folder and that file is there, but maybe something is wrong with this path - it is shorter only libxml/xmlversion.h ) ?

Comment: Looks like the library itself references its headers treating `/usr/local/include/libxml2/` as a root directory for its includes. As for me, this is strange, but adding this directory to 'C/C++ Build -> Settings -> GCC C Compiler -> Includes' should be a quick solution.

Comment: That worked and I can include headers from that library, however when I try to run an exmaple from that library I still get errors like "undefined reference to some methods". I checked headers I've included and they contain those methods, but it seems like .c files are missing here. Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Ok it works now, as you said I added path to C complier includes and 
xml2 to C Linker libraries - thanks a lot!