# C++: External library in eclipse CDT

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

Now I am using eclipse CDT for my C/C++ Application, but there is problem when I link my external library, it could not be loaded properly at run time, even through I put the library file near the source file, I gave the library path, and it's name correctly.

project directory:

1. include(.h files)
2. source(.cpp. files..)
3. lib(libbozorth3.a,LSFMatcher.a)

I want link that static libraries with my application I follow this steps:

1. project->properties->general->path and symbols->include directory path,and libraries(bozorth3.a,LSFMatcher.a),and add library path .
2. and also i add the same library in linker section also

When I build the program it displays a error
cannot find -lbozorth3.a
cannot find -lLSFMatcher.a

So I need the correct steps to add the external library to c/c++ application.

Comment: did you consider: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8370809/how-to-add-a-library-to-eclipse-c-project ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I normally configure

1. the library
2. the library search path (Needed for compiliation)
3. the runtime search path (-rpath Linker option)

(see images below and exchange the path in the Linker flags to that one you used in the library search path)

[image: Library Search path]
[image: Linker options for runtime search path]

Answer (score 2):

you should use `-Wl,-rpath=${workspace_loc}/Liball` and not `-Wl,-rpath,${workspace_loc}/Liball`.

Also under library -l option add library like eg. for libgcc.a add only gcc

Comment: This is not a full answer. It depends on the answer offered by FSaccilotto. Maybe you should move it to a comment so he can correct his post, or you should add more detail to yours so it is a full answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should pay attention to what is in parentheses: Other options (-Xlinker [option]).

The way to pass options is different. Instead of using:

```
-Wl,-rpath,'${ProjDirPath}/../../system/lib'
```

You must use:

```
-rpath '${ProjDirPath}/../../system/lib'
```

That is, remove the "-Wl," and replace the second "," by " " (space).

[image]

[image]