# Eclipse how to include files with relative path

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, include-path

I am new in Eclipse development. I am trying to migrate existing c++ project from visual studio to eclipse. 
Files I want to include files that are distributed in different folders in framework.

*framework/common* - contain common files

*framework/extra*  - contains extra files and so on.

Eclipse project is located in:

*framework/projects/rtree/*

in *main.cpp* I need to include different files from framework but i am not able to use same relative paths as in visual studio.

In project properties i have already set include folder to contain all folder. In current state, i am able to include files with absolute path. I.E.

```
#include "/home/pavlos/framework/common/helpers/someclass.h"
```

But I need to be able to do this:

```
#include "common/helpers/someclass.h
#include "extra/someclass2.h
```

Because all files in this framework uses these relative paths. I cannot change them because they are common for more projects. Is it somehow possible to achieve this ?

[screen shot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gbq8d97tz4srb3g/eclipse.png)

Thank you in advance, 
Pavlos

Answer (score 1):

To include files in eclipse for c++, you will need to add each library folder separately. From the screen-shot you have added only the base folder `"/home/pavlas/framework"` while in reality there are sub-directories in this folder as well. You will have to add these subdirectories as well like `"/home/pavlas/framework/commons"`, `"/home/pavlas/framework/extra"` and so on.

Comment: Thank you for an advice. It seems to be particially working. It works only if I define these includes in properties of main.cpp. When it is defined only in project properties, path is not recognized. Is there a way how to use includes from project properties ?

Comment: Take a look at this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8834883/c-external-library-in-eclipse-cdt)