# how to make a speech recognition app using pocketsphinx in eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, pocketsphinx-android

I need to develop a Speech Recognition app using `PocketSphinx` . Can you suggest me how to use `PocketSphinx` in `Eclipse`?

Comment: have you tried out with normal web based project?

Comment: no. I have a requirement like offline speech recognition app using pocketsphinx. That too I am using eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

1) Install Eclipse CDT to write code in C in Eclipse

2) Follow instructions in [C++: External library in eclipse CDT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8834883/c-external-library-in-eclipse-cdt) to add pocketsphinx library to your project

3) Implement the code you need based on [pocketsphinx tutorial](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialpocketsphinx).

Comment: Hello Nikolay, Need your guidance. I have downloaded the PocketSphinx Android project for Eclipse. I imported the code in Eclipse, did clean and build and run it. It ran successfully. Then I tried to put Speech Recognition in my own project. What I did was copied the libs folder files to my project and asset folder files to my project. I edited words in the .gram file and tried to run it. Is this way correct or do I need to do something else?

Comment: One thing I noticed was, when I did clean build of Demo project then it used to delete `.gram.md5` files and recreated them when I ran the project on device. But when I did clean build my own project, it did not recreated the `.gram.md5` files. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Actually this thing worked for sometime but after a few times of running the project it started showing me `\1e-1\` does not exist in the `.gram` file. However it was there. I referred to your answer here, http://stackoverflow.com/a/25749377/995009

Comment: P.S. SourceForge is down for maintenance.